# discrete fourier transform in Matlab - theoretical confusion

Tags: algorithm, matlab, fft, dft

I have a periodic term

```
v(x) = sum over K of [exp(iKx) V(K) ]
```

where K =2*pi*n/a where a is the periodicity of the term and n =0,1,2,3....

Now I want to find the Fourier coefficient V(K) corresponding to a particular K. Suppose I have a vector for v(x) having 10000 points for

```
x = 0,0.01a,0.02a,...a,1.01a,....2a....100a
```

such that the size of my lattice is 100a. FFT on this vector gives 10000 Fourier coefficients. The K values corresponding to these Fourier coefficients are 2*pi*n/(10000*0.01) with n=0,1,2,3,...9999.

But my K had the form 2*pi*n/a due to the periodicity of the lattice. What am I missing ?

Comment: Your notation is pretty hard to follow.  Also, this could well be off-topic (as it seems to be a signal-processing/maths theory problem - maybe better-suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: dsp.stackexchage.com is non-functional in my location, it seems- it opens a page with just stackexchange written on it.

Comment: Ooops, typo.  It's http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function probably is not complex, so you will need negative frequencies in the complex Fourier series expression. During the FFT this does not matter since the negative frequencies are aliased to the higher positive frequencies, but in the expression as continuous function this could give strange results.

That means that the range of n is from -N/2 to N/2-1 if N is the size of the sampling.

Note that the points you have given are 10001 in number if you start at 0a with 0.01a steps and end at 100a. So the last point for N=10000 points should be 100a-0.01a=99.99a.

Your sampling frequency is the reciprocal of the sampling step, Fs=1/(0.01a). The frequencies of the FFT are then 2*pi*n/N*Fs=2*pi*n/(10000*0.01a)=2*pi*n/(100*a), every 100th of them corresponds to one of your K.

This is not astonishing since the sampling is over 100 periods of the function, the longer period results in a much lower basic frequency. If the signal v(x) is truly periodic, all amplitudes except the ones for n divisible by 100 will be zero. If the signal is not exactly periodic due to noise and measurement errors, the peaks will leak out into neighboring frequencies. For a correct result for the original task you will have to integrate the amplitudes over the peaks.

Comment: so the frequencies will extend from 2*pi*n/a where n = -N/2 to N/2-1 and the 100th one will be of the form I need ? yes, that makes sense but can you confirm please ? I mean, if I need a fourier coefficient for a negative frequency, so will I have to look at a higher positive frequency, let us suppose I have to look at -4*pi/a. So which positive frequency I will look- taking -2*N*pi/a as the new zero or continuing the negative frequencies after half of the positive frequencies are done with. I shall accept your answer once my doubts is clear. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Not exactly. After the FFT with N=10000 and over 100 periods you get some array say amp[k] with k=0,...,9999. amp[k] is the amplitude for frequency 2*pi*k/(100*a). If k=100*n, this reduces to some K=2*pi*n/a. But if there is noise over the 100 periods, then also amp[100*n+k] for k=-5,...,5 or so may contain appreciable contributions that originally came from frequency K.